# Is it possible in either HTML or CSS to prompt a user to choose a set of colours in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, colors

I've just been performing some browser testing, and noticed a pop-up that appeared during one of my tests using Firefox that prompted me to choose various colours; there was also a button labelled "Add to Custom Colors". I would say that I'm a power user of both Firefox and Chrome, and have never seen this promtp before; it appears to have been generated from one of the URLs that had been loaded in the background, but unfortunately I don't have the address to hand. I haven't been able to find anything useful during my searching efforts - is there a piece of HTML or CSS that could trigger such a pop-up?

Comment: You might be looking for this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_color.asp

Comment: It depends on the browser what color picker is shown.

Comment: @g_bor - Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. :) Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might be looking for a html from field with input type color. This input type shows a browser dependent color picker, and browsers not implementing anything typically fall back as if the type was simply text.
You can find more information about it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_color.asp

Answer (score 1):

The [color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color) value for the `type` attribute of an `input` is supported in all modern browsers.

The UI will vary from browser to browser (and may use an OS-native UI).

```html
<input type="color" value="#e66465" id="color_picker">
<label for="color_picker">Pick a colour</label>
```